# Remote Desktop Services License on two Windows 2008 servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop-services

Is it possible to share the same retail Remote Desktop Services License key across two different Windows 2008 servers on the same domain?

My small business currently has a retail RDS License for 5 users. I would like to include two servers in that count. Meaning if my coworker and I are both using RDP on the two servers, that would use up 4 TS License users within the same domain.

Please correct me if I'm thinking about this the wrong way. I'm having a hard time finding out if this is possible.

Comment: TS cals are installed on the licensing server, and then associated with either users or devices that are connecting, depending on the licensing mode you chose.  You can have terminal services functionality enabled on as many servers as you want, so long as you have a windows server license for that machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You install the CALs on a server that has the Remote Desktop Licensing role on it. That server can be configured to "hand out" CALs to any number of Remote Desktop Session Hosts in your organization. So, yes, what you are proposing is not only possible, it's quite common.

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983943(v=ws.10).aspx) covers pretty much everything that you need to know.